# List of inverse and polarity flip words required

Tags: data-request, language, english

I'm a computer science student and I'm doing a research on sentimental analysis with a large database. Therefore, i need to create dictionaries to mapping words. 
 Now i'm facing the problem of "Double Negation" in my project.

For an example:

> "The eggplant is not bad."
>   contains the word bad but the sentence is a positive opinion about the eggplant. This is because the appearance of the negation word not, that flips the meaning of the negative adjective bad.

We could take into account these types of polarity flips defining a dictionary of inverters:

**inv.yml**

`lack of: [inv]
not: [inv]`

To fill this script i need hundreds of inverse words to get a good accuracy. 
can anyone **help me to find a list of inverse word** that can cause double negation. 
Any answer appreciated.

thank you

Comment: This question doesn't suck.